# How to inject service in $ionicActionSheet

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I'm trying to call function `deleteConv` which is inside service `ChatsService`  from $ionicActionSheet, but it failed. I had an error `Error: ChatsService.deleteConversation(...) is undefined`even though service is defined and  injected controller

```
  /**
  Controller
**/     
    angular.module('Tot.controllers')
        .controller('MessageController', function($scope, $timeout,ChatsService,$localStorage,,Globals,$ionicActionSheet,Messages) {


            var iduser=$localStorage[Globals.USER_LOGGED].id;
            $scope.onConversationHold = function(e, itemIndex, conversation) {
                $ionicActionSheet.show({
                    cancelText:'<span class="no-text-transform">Annuler</span>',
                    destructiveText: '<span class="no-text-transform">Supprimer</span>',
                    destructiveButtonClicked: function() {
                        ChatsService.deleteConversation(conversation,iduser).then(function(response){
                            alert(response);

                            return true; //Close the model?

                        })
                    }
                });
            };

    });



/**
ChatsService.js
**/
angular.module('Tot.services')
    .service('ChatsService', function($q,$http,Globals) {
        var url=Globals.urlServer+Globals.port;
        this.deleteConversation=function(conversation,iduser){
            var deferred=$q.defer();
            $http.get(url+'/conversation/deleteConversation?idconversation='+conversation+'&iduser='+iduser).success(function(response){
                if(response)
                {
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

How can I fix it ?

[EDITED]

```
  /**
    app.js
**/

        angular.module('Tot', ['ionic','Tot.controllers','Tot.services','Tot.constants'])
        .run(function($ionicPlatform,Messages,$rootScope,$cordovaStatusbar, $state,Globals,$localStorage,$mdDialog,$mdToast) {
          $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
              cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
              // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required

              //StatusBar.styleDefault();
              $cordovaStatusbar.overlaysWebView(true);
              $cordovaStatusbar.styleHex('#c62828')

            }
        ....
        })
```

Comment: pretty sure you should be injecting your service into your module, can you make a codepen or post some more code please?

Comment: @JessPatton I updated my question with the whole controller and services

Answer (score 0):

okay so I am pretty sure you just need to inject the Tot.service module into your Tot.controller module. so the Tot.controller module should look like

```
angular.module('Tot.controllers', ['Tot.services'])
        .controller('MessageController', function($scope, $timeout,ChatsService,$localStorage,,Globals,$ionicActionSheet,Messages) {


            var iduser=$localStorage[Globals.USER_LOGGED].id;
            $scope.onConversationHold = function(e, itemIndex, conversation) {
                $ionicActionSheet.show({
                    cancelText:'<span class="no-text-transform">Annuler</span>',
                    destructiveText: '<span class="no-text-transform">Supprimer</span>',
                    destructiveButtonClicked: function() {
                        ChatsService.deleteConversation(conversation,iduser).then(function(response){
                            alert(response);

                            return true; //Close the model?

                        })
                    }
                });
            };

    });
```

Similar to injecting ionic into your main module for you app. Modules have to be injected into other modules in order to access services and controllers inside those modules. That should work for you. let me know if it doesn't and I will have another look.

Comment: `Tot.service` is already injected in `app.js`  as you can see in my question(edited)  so I think it's not necessary to inject it again in `Tot.controllers`

Comment: Well try it and tell me what happens and then I will look at it again

Comment: No success , I would like to remind that others functions in ChatsService call outside the $ionicActionSheet  from  Tot.Controllers run without problem

Comment: hey can you make a codepen? or just put your code on github so I can grab it and debug it a little?